# Access a variable within a sub function within a service function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have the following service:

```
function Configuration($http, $q) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.$q = $q;

    this.promises = [];

    this.getEnv().then(function(d) {
        this.env = d;
    });
}

Configuration.prototype.getEnv = function() {

    // only go get the environment setting if we don't already have it

    var deferred = this.$q.defer();

    if (this.promises.length > 0) {

        console.log('%cAdd to queue', 'color:orange;');
        this.promises.push(deferred);

    } else if (!this.env) {
        this.promises.push(deferred);
        console.log('%cFetch from live', 'color:red');

        // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
        var promise = this.$http.get('config/env.json').then(function(response) {
            // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
            console.log("environment variable is " + response.data.current_environment);
            // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
            this.env = response.data.current_environment;

            var i;
            for (i = this.promises.length; i--;) {
                console.log('%cYay! Resolving the existing promises with a single server side request', 'color:white;background:deepskyblue');
                this.promises.shift().resolve(this.env);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('%cFetch direct from this.env', 'color:green');
        deferred.resolve(this.env);
    }

    // Return the promise to the controller
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I am in the process of debugging the promises cache that i am building to prevent multiple hits to the server.  unfortunatly the JS engine in chrome is much faster than Apache.  The concept is simple, basically log the promises in a cache, if the method is hit, if there is no promise in the cache, run it, if there are promises in the cache, then don't execute it.

My problem occures in the `for (i = this.promises.length; i--;) {` What happens is the this.promises is undefined.  Im assuming its because its inside of a nested function and its normal JS variable scope doesn't allow it to access variables in the parent functions.  But im not sure.

Is there a way I can make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cache `this` outside the `$http` promise callback, because inside the callback you are no longer in your service instance's context :-

```
    var _this = this; //<-- Here

    var promise = this.$http.get('config/env.json').then(function(response) {


        _this.env = response.data.current_environment;

        var i;
        for (i = _this.promises.length; i--;) {

            _this.promises.shift().resolve(_this.env);
        }
    });
```

Or Bind the service instance's context to the callback.

```
   this.$http.get('config/env.json').then((function(response) {
        // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
        console.log("environment variable is " + response.data.current_environment);
        // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
        this.env = response.data.current_environment;

        var i;
        for (i = this.promises.length; i--;) {
            console.log('%cYay! Resolving the existing promises with a single server side request', 'color:white;background:deepskyblue');
            this.promises.shift().resolve(this.env);
        }
    }).bind(this))
```

Comment: beautiful, i figured it was something stupid like that.  Your first one worked like a charm.  Second one didn't for some reason.  Not sure why.  But either way, thank you